# Django admin inheritance

Tags: python, django, admin

simple question: is it possible to organize all this info in one admin form only instead of 6 separated links?

i've read about django admin inheritance but there is no inheritance among the models, as shown below...so how would it work then?

models.py

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class User(models.Model):
 name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
 bdate = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name='Data de Nasc.')
 gender = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Sexo')
 cpf = models.CharField(max_length=14, unique=True, verbose_name='CPF')
 oab = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True, verbose_name='OAB')
 phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Celular')
 email = models.EmailField(max_length=50, verbose_name='E-mail')

 def __unicode__(self):
  return self.name

 class Meta:
  verbose_name = u'1.Identificação'
  verbose_name_plural = u'1.Identificação'

class Address(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
 cep = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='CEP')
 address = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'Endereço')
 bairro = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Bairro')
 city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Cidade')
 uf = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Estado')

 class Meta:
  verbose_name = u'2.Endereço'
  verbose_name_plural = u'2.Endereço'

class Pretensoes(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
 cargo = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Cargo pretendido')
 salario = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Salario pretendido')
 cidade1 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Cidade 1', default=None)
 cidade2 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Cidade 2', default=None)
 cidade3 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Cidade 3', default=None)
 cidade4 = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Cidade 4',default=None)

 class Meta:
  verbose_name = u'3.Pretensões'
  verbose_name_plural = u'3.Pretensões'

class Graduation(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
 scholarity = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Escolaridade')
 course = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'Área/Curso')
 school = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=u'Instituição')
 year = models.CharField(max_length=4, verbose_name=u'Ano de conclusão')
 others = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name='Outros')
 msword = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Word')
 msexcel = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Excel')
 msinternet = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Internet')

 class Meta:
  verbose_name = u'4.Escolaridade'
  verbose_name_plural = u'4.Escolaridade'

class Professional(models.Model):
 user = models.ForeignKey(User, default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
 company = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Empresa')
 start = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=u'Mês de entrada')
 end = models.CharField(max_length=10, verbose_name=u'Mês de saída')
 p_city = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Cidade')
 p_phone = models.CharField(max_length=15, verbose_name='Telefone')
 functions = models.CharField(max_length=300, verbose_name=u'Funções')

 class Meta:
  verbose_name = u'5.Profissional'
  verbose_name_plural = u'5.Profissional'

class Info(models.Model):
 user = models.OneToOneField(User, default=0, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Nome Completo')
 info = models.TextField(verbose_name=u'Demais informações relevantes')

 class Meta:
  verbose_name = u'6.Demais informações'
  verbose_name_plural = u'6.Demais informações'
```

admin.py

```html
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from django.contrib import admin
from models import User, Address, Pretensoes, Graduation, Professional, Info

# Register your models here.
class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'name',
        'bdate',
        'gender',
        'cpf',
        'oab',
        'phone',
        'email',
    ]

class AddressAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'user',
        'cep',
        'address',
        'bairro',
        'city',
        'uf',
    ]

class PretensoesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'user',
        'cargo',
        'salario',
        'cidade1',
        'cidade2',
        'cidade3',
        'cidade4',
    ]

    search_fields = ['cargo', 'salario']

class GraduationAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'user',
        'scholarity',
        'course',
        'school',
        'year',
        'others',
        'msword',
        'msexcel',
        'msinternet',
    ]

    list_filter = (
     ('scholarity'), 
     ('msword'),
     ('msexcel'),
     ('msinternet'),
    )

    search_fields = ['scholarity', 'course', 'school', 'year', 'msword', 'msexcel', 'msinternet']
    

class ProfessionalAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'user',
        'company',
        'start',
        'end',
        'p_city',
        'p_phone',
        'functions',
    ]

class InfoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = [
        'user',
        'info',
    ]

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
admin.site.register(Address, AddressAdmin)
admin.site.register(Pretensoes, PretensoesAdmin)
admin.site.register(Graduation, GraduationAdmin)
admin.site.register(Professional, ProfessionalAdmin)
admin.site.register(Info, InfoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use admin model inline :)

```
from django.contrib import admin

from .models import Choice, Question


class AddressInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Address


class UserAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AddressInline]

admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

You can use multiple inlines as well for like foreign keys and such, try it out it was in the polls tutorial https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial02/

Bloop Bloop happy djangoing!